# Non spatial atomic topos

Tags: topos-theory, ct.category-theory

Hello !

If I'm not mistaken, an atomic topos decompose as a disjoint sum of connected atomic topos, and Connected Atomic topos with a point corresponds to classifying topos of localic groups.

But what about conected atomic topos without point ? do we know what they look like ?

I actually know no example of these non-spatial atomic topos. So if a 'classification' of them is not possible, any example will already be interesting.

Thank you !

Comment: There is an example of a pointless connected atomic topos: see Example 3.4.14 in [_Sketches of an elephant_, Part D].

Comment: I added the [ct.category-theory] tag.

Comment: @Zhen - why not add that as an answer, or even better, write it out? Not everyone has access to the Elephant (it does cost a small fortune after all).

Comment: I would if I understood the construction myself!

Comment: @David, concerning Elephants, contact me. I don't seem to have your current email address.